# How I Can End Editing with Scroll View?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I usually use this function to hide the keyboard once any point in screen is touched

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

But when I use it with scroll view it doesn't work.

How I can hide the keyboard once any point of scroll view is touched ?

Answer (score 5):

Try set `keyboardDismissMode` of `UIScrollView` to `OnDrag` or `Interactive`, it's default to `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeNone`

> The manner in which the keyboard is dismissed when a drag begins in the scroll view.

Comment: Sorry, But I didn't understand. I am a novice

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe in `viewDidLoad`, do something like: `self.scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.Interactive`

Comment: I didn't even know that after years of iOS development, old post but it made my day thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add tap gesture recognizer to scrollView object.

```
let touch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "singleTapGestureCaptured:")
  scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(touch)
```

and receive the touch event and hide keyboard.

```
func singleTapGestureCaptured(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
  }
```

Comment: I understand and use swift. Is this objective C?.

Comment: Can you write it with swift, please.

Answer (score 0):

There is delegate function for scrollview - "scrollview did scroll" you can dismiss the keyboard there.